# Example usage of TA-LIB trader_sma function?

Tags: php, ta-lib

I just installed TA-Lib / trader into my php installation and it's good to go. My PHP isn't great and even with the trader documentation I just need a bit of guidance. I want to load an array of values from my database and send them into "trader_sma" to get the small moving average. My pseudo code will look something like:

```
<?php

$finance = $dbrequest("SELECT close_price FROM market_table WHERE stock='$symbol');

//So now $finance is an array with all of the stocks closing prices
//how do I place it into this function? I also need to 'count' the rows in
//the array to send them into $timePeriod?

//array trader_sma ( array $real [, integer $timePeriod ] )


?>
```

Any help appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

`$real` will be the values you are inputting and `$timePeriod` is an integer that specifies the length of the moving average.

Therefore you would use the function like this:

```
$real = array(12,15,17,19,21,25,28,12,15,16);
$timePeriod = 3;
$data = trader_sma($real,$timePeriod);
var_dump($data);
```

The output will be array of a three increment moving average...

12 + 15 + 17 = 34
34 / 3 = 11.333

```
array(float 11.333,
      float 17, etc...
```

Comment: 12+15+17 =44. 44/3 = 14.66667. just for correctness.